# Object arrays without shape not supported issue in Spyder 4.1.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I'm working with python 3.7.6 on 64-bit Windows 10 (v 1909) and just updated anaconda navigator to v 1.1.10 and Spyder to 4.1.5. Trying to open a .npy file with "data = np.load('filename.npy', allow_pickle=True)" at IPython console (7.19.0).  The data loads into the variable viewer, however i cannot view the contents.  it simply shows "ndarray object of numpy module" as the Value, and attempting to open it further yields the error "Object arrays without shape are not supported"

I've read in previous documentation that support for this was supposed to come in Spyder v4.  Also, view with the Object Explorer doesnt offer any additional information -- just shows some various built-in methods i can use on "data".  The "Callable" column for the loaded "data" variable in Object Explorer is "False".
Hoping someone here can help me identify the problem.

Comment: " however i cannot view the contents. " I take it you mean you can't use the variable explorer. So what? You can still extract whatever information you need.

Comment: what's the best way to do this? is "print(data)" the only way to view the information? forgive me, i am relatively beginner in python (switching over from MATLAB) -- chose this IDE because many recommend it for folks like me

Comment: So, what ist `type(data)`? If it is a `numpy.ndarray`, then what is `data.dtype` and `data.shape`? If the `.shape` is `()`, then what is `type(data[()])`?

Comment: `type(data)` is `numpy.ndarray`, and `data.dtype` and `data.shape` yield `dtype('0')` and `()`, respectively

Comment: Ok, what's `type(data[()])` give you?

Comment: `type(data[()])` is `dict`

Comment: ok. So there you have it. But why was some dict saved as a `.npy` in a zero-dimensional numpy array? Seems like whatever the source of the data here is the problem

Comment: that is an excellent question. an open source software i've been applying to mouse behavioral video data outputs a `.npy` file in this way, and i'm not sure why that design decision was made.  I'll have to dig deeper into the syntax of accessing `dict` items.  loading the file with `.item()` appended after the `np.load()` fxn seems to allow easier access to the contents (`data["relevant_var_name"]`).  thanks alot for your help -- i would have banged my head against the wall over this syntax all day

Comment: Yes, `array.item()` is useful here. In general, you want to avoid the `object` dtype